# Why are Nominal Items/Recurring Profiles not affected by shopping cart price rules?

Tags: promotions, recurring, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am working with Recurring Profiles and I'm trying to understand why the promotion "shopping cart price rules" don't apply for these items? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> "Nominal items are not added to regular totals (taxes, subtotal, and grand total)." [(source)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles)

Discounts occur through totals models which are not involved with the calculation of nominal products. Why this is the case? Probably to either ship the feature on time or to reduce complexity, given that there are already three separate totals models involved in the calculation of nominal products.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. It has more info about nominal products and their behaviour.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post, but I'm looking for more of an explanation as to why reoccurring orders are treated this way and why the shopping carts promo rules aren't applicable